# "Давно не проветриваемое помещение" - почему НЕ раздельно?

Tags: причастия

Не судимый мною (причастие), судимый в этом контексте - причастие, так как пояснительное слово в творительном падеже.

Ранее несудимый (прилагательное), судимый в этом контексте - прилагательное, так пояснительное не в творительном падеже.

Никем не судимый(прилагательное), прилагательное пишем раздельно, так как есть отрицательное местоимение.

Не проветриваемое мною помещение - причастие, пишем раздельно.

Тогда почему *давно не проветриваемое помещение* - рекомендуют писать раздельно?

Ведь пояснительное слово - не в творительном падеже (то есть это не причастие), следовательно, это прилагательное, а так как нет отрицательных местоимений и наречий, а также частиц далеко не, отнюдь не, то писать должны слитно.

Они не взаимозаменяемы - пишет Грамота. Взаимозаменять - такого глагола в словаре Лопатина нет. Но в Национальном корпусе и в Интернете встречается, например: В салатах компоненты можно взаимозаменять без ущерба для вкуса.

Это глагол переходной, несовершенного вида и в зависимости от контекста может быть причастием и прилагательным. Если пояснительное слово в творительном падеже, то это причастие. Если нет пояснительных слов или другие пояснительные слова, то это прилагательное и с НЕ пишется раздельно при наличии отрицательных местоимений и наречий, а также частиц далеко не, отнюдь не. В остальных случаях слитно. Может быть в предложении *Они не взаимозаменяемы* НЕ пишется раздельно, так как выступает в роли сказуемого? А в предложении *Невзаимозаменяемые компоненты* необходимо было писать слитно. С другой стороны, если это прилагательное, то при отрицании утверждения пишется по общему правилу раздельно с НЕ. Или это правило не относится к прилагательным на -мый?

Answer (score 5):

Никем не судимый  **причастие**, есть отрицательное местоимение, да ещё в творит. падеже, пишем раздельно.

```
 Тогда почему давно не проветриваемое помещение - рекомендуют
писать раздельно?Ведь пояснительное  слово - не в творительном падеже 
(то есть это не причастие),   следовательно,   это прилагательное.
```

Нет, не прилагательное, здесь нет качественного признака (ср.непроветриваемое помещение=душное).В данном контексте "давно не проветриваемое помещение" - то, которое давно не проветривали, это признак по действию, т.е.причастие.

Они не взаимозаменяемы - отрицает факт взаимозаменяемости.

Невзаимозаменяемые компоненты  -  утверждается незаменяемость.

Answer (score 1):

Проветривать - глагол несовершенного вида, переходный. Значит, ***(не)проветриваемое*** - ***причастие***, а не отглагольное прилагательное.

У этого причастия ***есть зависимое слово***: не проветриваемое ***как долго?* *давно.* Не пишется раздельно.**

**Невзаимозаменяемые - прилагательное.**

В вашем случае НЕ ВЗАИМОЗАМЕНЯЕМЫ предполагает отрицание, противопоставление, поэтому пишется раздельно. Но возможно и слитное написание НЕВЗАИМОЗАМЕНЯЕМЫ по правилу написания прилагательных с НЕ. Смотря какой смысл вкладывается в слово.

Answer (score 1):

1) [Розенталь. § 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)

Следует помнить, что слова на -мый, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, могут быть как страдательными причастиями настоящего времени (частица не с ними пишется раздельно), так и прилагательными (частица не с ними пишется слитно).
Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется **творительный действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия**: не любимый матерью ребёнок; движение, не тормозимое воздухом.
**При наличии других пояснительных слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на -мый (они теряют значения страдательности и приобретают качественное значение)**: нелюбимые в детстве игры (слово нелюбимый указывает на постоянный признак и значит примерно то же, что неприятный, нежелательный); не посещаемые охотниками заповедники; не читаемые неспециалистами журналы; невидимая с Земли сторона Луны; неделимое на три число; незабываемые для нас встречи; непередаваемые простыми словами чувства; непроходимая в весеннюю пору грязь; нетерпимое в обществе поведение.

Вывод: давно непроветриваемое помещение (прилагательное).

2) **Они невзаимозаменяемы/они не взаимозаменяемы** (прилагательные). Возможные оба варианта (отрицание и утверждение), чаще используется раздельное написание.

Схема образования: заменять - заменяемые - взаимозаменяемые - невзаимозаменяемые.

Примеры: Хотя льняное масло, как и рыбий жир, является источником омега-3, они невзаимозаменяемы, поскольку поставляют разные типы жирных кислот этого вида. Они не взаимозаменяемы, потому что воспитывают разные формы мышления.