# Непроветриваемый — это причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: грамматика, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные, причастия, части-речи

***Непроветриваемый*** — это какой?  И это **прилагательное или нет?**

При слитном написании ***НЕ*** должен быть **пояснительный текст**: какой именно? На Грамоте.ру я не могу найти нужную информацию.

**Пример**

*Тоннель Канонерского острова длинный, плохо освещенный, **непроветриваемый,** а потому заполненный выхлопными газами.* Герман Садулаев. Таблетка (2008).

**Примечание**

Вопрос обсуждался **на форуме** в темах [1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423661/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%AB%D0%99-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8) и [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423626/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%9D%D0%95-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE) (слитное и раздельное написание НЕ). Но по ответам трудно сделать вывод о грамматической принадлежности слова.  К тому же **[по Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)** слова на -МЫЙ считаются **прилагательными** при отсутствии зависимых слов в Т.п.

**РОЗЕНТАЛЬ**

14. Следует помнить, что слова на *-мый*, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, могут быть как страдательными **причастиями** настоящего времени (частица *не* с ними пишется раздельно), так и **прилагательными** (частица *не* с ними пишется слитно).

Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется **творительный** действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия: *не любимый матерью ребёнок; движение, не тормозимое воздухом*.

При наличии **других пояснительных** слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на *-мый* (они **теряют значения страдательности** и приобретают **качественное** значение): *нелюбимые в детстве игры* (слово *нелюбимый* указывает на постоянный признак и значит примерно то же, что *неприятный, нежелательный*); *не посещаемые охотниками заповедники; не читаемые неспециалистами журналы; невидимая с Земли сторона Луны; неделимое на три число; незабываемые для нас встречи; непередаваемые простыми словами чувства; непроходимая в весеннюю пору грязь; нетерпимое в обществе поведение.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю так.
Все без исключения слова (в том числе ***непроветриваемый***), во всех примерах, являются причастиями.
Любое слово, образованное от глагола путем добавления морфологических и качественных свойств прилагательного, является причастием.
Часть речи "причастие" (а тем более, как мы привыкли, одна из особых форм глагола) может существовать только тогда, когда несет в себе обе стороны. Симбиоз глагольности и прилагательности – обязательный фактор для возможности называться причастием.

Глагол – мама (мама-глагол видна без очков и слышна).
К глаголу приложился папа-прилагательное.
В итоге родился ребенок с именем ***причастие*** – особая форма (опять же) глагола или отдельная часть речи, являющаяся метисом.

Такие мысли возникли в результате обсуждения моего ответа на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478760/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), и только благодаря ему.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, Александр, интересный у вас ответ, **оригинальный даже**. Не все с вами согласятся, но хотя бы задумаются)

1. **Декомпозиция насмотренности?** Любопытное понятие. А что это такое? В словаре ничего не нашлось, ближайший вариант:

**НАСМОТРЕТЬ,** -смотрю, -смотришь; насмотренный; -рен, -а, -о; св. кого-что. Нар.-разг. **Рассмотреть, увидеть; высмотреть**. Н. себе невесту. Н. дачу.

**ДЕКОМПОЗИЦИЯ** [дэ] и [де], -и; ж. [лат. de- и compositio]. Разделение, расчленение какой-л. **сложной структуры** на составляющие части. Д. задачи. Принципы декомпозиции.

2. Но термин есть в сети, например: **[Что такое насмотренность и зачем она нужна?](https://dzen.ru/a/ZQxIxNbyAwZ22NKU)**

**Чем полезна насмотренность креативщикам?** Помимо вышеизложенного, насмотренность позволяет оставаться на волне **трендов**, поскольку постоянный просмотр **актуальных решений** позволит не только видеть все самые новые веяния, но и на основе опыта создавать **собственные тренды и креативы.** Ничто не развивает творческие навыки лучше чем огромный багаж визуальных исследований признанных шедевров.

3. Вот только **насмотренность бывает разной**. Например, возможна  насмотренность относительно этимологических словарей. Я имею в виду
   **[Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/Spravochniki/istoriko-etimologicheskij-slovar-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka/).**  Может быть, надо учитывать значение древних **корней:** признак или действие считается основным для конкретного слова.
4. Да и так ли **велика эта разница**? Ведь глагол — это процессуальный признак предмета. Как вам такая формулировка?

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**[Самое трудное в орфографии правило](https://proza.ru/2021/06/22/598)**

**[Палящее солнце](https://proza.ru/2023/07/07/1496)**

*Итак, причастие или прилагательное — вот вечный вопрос! **Может быть, нужна новая идея?**  Какие неточности можно отметить при ответах с новыми идеями? Прежде всего, нужно точно следовать толковому словарю. Вывод. Идея может быть полезной и нужной, но на пути к ее реализации очень много подводных камней. Поэтому все должно быть тщательно продумано))*

*P. S. О «бредовых» стихах. Говорят, что бред бывает вполне **совместим с гениальностью))** Мне стихи понравились, это классно!
Нам уже скучно воспринимать мир последовательно, но хочется представить его целостный образ. И тогда мы перечисляем несовместимые предметы в виде однородного ряда…*

*У вас появилась очередная **странная идея?** Такие идеи бывают от странных стихов... Боже вас сохрани, не читайте их больше. Вы ведь не поэт, нет? Эти стихи нужны только для вдохновения))*

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! *"Ведь глагол — это процессуальный признак предмета. Как вам такая формулировка?"* Отличная и понятная формулировка. // Да... Вчера для меня был знаковый день. Можно сказать, только сейчас начался новый год, открылись глаза... Всегда ли завиральный – это плохо? // Снова смотрю про части речи... может, напишу еще что-нибудь, когда-нибудь. // Стишок понравился, Варвара!

Comment: Это же не ее стишок! Из мультфильма!  Для настроения. //  То, что происходит в нашей жизни (новые идеи, встречи с новыми людьми и т. д.) необходимо для развития личности. Все как бы идет по плану-сценарию, о котором мы не всегда знаем)) Успехов вам и творческого настроения.