# Что означает словосочетание "давно не проветриваемое помещение"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные, причастия, части-речи

Конечно, все скажут, что это душное помещение, которое **давно не проветривали.** Но мне непонятна его **ГРАММАТИКА**, то есть почему это страдательное **причастие** настоящего времени? (По правилам Розенталя это вроде бы **прилагательное**.)

Мне хотелось бы получить ответ на такой **вопрос:**
*Какое утверждение неверно и как объяснить 5 и 6?*

1. **Проветриваемое** помещение — это (1) помещение, которое можно проветрить (есть окна); (2) помещение, которое сейчас проветривают.
2. **Непроветриваемое** помещение — это помещение, которое нельзя проветрить (нет окон).
3. Это **проветриваемое**   помещение  (его можно проветрить и его сейчас проветривают).
4. Это **не проветриваемое** сейчас помещение  (его сейчас не проветривают).
5. Это **давно проветриваемое** помещение (как объяснить?)
6. Это **давно не проветриваемое** помещение (как объяснить?)

**Страдательные причастия** настоящего времени – группа страдательных причастий, обозначающих признак по действию, которое направлено на определяемый предмет и происходит **одновременно с основным действием** в предложении (т. е. в настоящем времени). Образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида.

Примеры страдательных причастий настоящего времени в словосочетаниях: **рисуемый художником** портрет, **огибаемый рекой** остров, **задаваемые учителем** вопросы.

**[Источник](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/stradatelnye-prichastiya-nastoyashhego-vremeni)**

**P. S.**  Пока писала вопрос, у меня появилась версия **ответа**, но мне хотелось бы услышать нечто подобное от вас.

Comment: Я уже пишу, но не знаю, когда закончу.

Comment: Я подожду, интересно!

Comment: Ого! Не ожидала от вас, где это вы начитались таких вольностей? А я вас считала верным адептом и последователем всех правил вообще и Розенталя в частности.

Comment: От Майтрейда!.. // Первым всегда трудно.

Comment: Оно и заметно, с кем поведешься. Осторожней, Майтрейд!  Кстати, Л. давно уж спать отпросился. Ну что, закроем тему?  Я предложу свою версию публике в другой теме, больше нечего предлагать, а вам спасибо за участие в обсуждении.

Comment: Спасибо, мне давно не было так интересно! Про Л. пока ничего не знаю. // Подправлю вопрос так, для видимости, чтобы стать ближе к знаку "просветитель"? :))

Comment: Да мы с ним немного поговорили еще и разошлись. Давайте, для видимости нужно.

Comment: Sharon, только сейчас понял, о каком Л. была речь (прочитал в чате, где вы уединились). А вчера подумал на другого :))  Для себя: на слово *кстати* нужно больше внимания обращать, тем более когда оно очень кстати, как у вас здесь.

Comment: Ну да,  он считает, что тире может заменить дефис,  – имейте в виду!  Какая разница-то? Ну и "робо" отчего бы не считать иноязычной приставкой.  В общем, предлагает тотальную декодификацию))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Проветриваемое** помещение — это (1) помещение, которое можно проветрить (есть окна); (2) помещение, которое сейчас проветривают.

**Верно**. Стадательное причастие настоящего времени. Значение под цифрой (1)  это как простое настоящее время, а под цифрой (2) продолженное. То есть в первом значении причастие приобретает постоянный признак, характерный прилагательному. Но на то оно и причастие, чтобы и нашим и вашим (симбиоз). Всё равно глагольная составляющая чувствуется больше.

2. **Непроветриваемое** помещение — это помещение, которое нельзя проветрить (нет окон).

**Верно**. То же, что и в первом. Значение только (1).

3. Это **проветриваемое** помещение (его можно проветрить и его сейчас проветривают).

**Верно**. То же, что и в первом. Но в значении (2) так никто не скажет, скажут "это помещение [сейчас] проветривают/проветривается".

4. Это **не проветриваемое сейчас** помещение (его сейчас не проветривают).

С формальной точки зрения **оба значения верны**. В значении (1) отрицание признака (раздельное написание с ***не***).
Но так не скажут.

5. Это **давно проветриваемое** помещение (как объяснить?)

Подходит только первое значение. Помещение давно [стало] проветриваемое/проветриваем**ым**.
В значении (2) скажут "давно проветр**енное**"

6. Это **давно не проветриваемое** помещение (как объяснить?)

Значение (1) подходит. Отрицание постоянного признака.
При слитном написании: помещение давно [стало] непроветриваемое/**-ым**.
В значении (2) скажут "давно не проветрива**вшееся**".

**P. S.** Дополнения, изменения, пояснения, скорее всего, еще будут.

Вот **первое** дополнение:
***рисуемый художником** портрет* – причастие, значение только (1);
**огибаемый рекой** остров – оба значения (сейчас огибается? – огибается);
***задаваемые учителем** вопросы* – оба значения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне нужно увидеть во всех вариантах действие, которое  в настоящий момент совершается или не совершается. И вот этого действия я не вижу, пока не добавляю "сейчас". А "давно" не укладывается в моей голове. Как может быть сейчас, если это давно.  Наблюдатель должен видеть это действие как сейчас протекающее.

Comment: Действие совершается сейчас, оно постоянно, это сближение с прилагательным, но действие превалирует по форме образования слова, и поэтому беря на себя функции прилагательного, слово становится истинным причастием – словом, в котором обязательно должно быть и от мамы, и от папы.

Comment: Какая сложная философия))  Вот и я думаю, что-то здесь не то.  Нельзя проверять действие по определению из книги.  Потом думаю дальше: кто проветривал, тот и был свидетелем того, как действие  совершается в их настоящий момент. Как вам такая философия?

Comment: Что кто-то был свидетелем и сейчас наблюдает сомнений нет.

Comment: А это самое главное.  Кстати,  до сих пор наблюдает? Ну а следующий (контрольный) вывод за вами: что с Розенталем-то делать? По правилам давно в качестве зависимого слова не проходит. У него это прилагательное, что ли?

Comment: Сейчас еще больше убеждаюсь в том, что причастие ни с чем не спутаешь. Оно изначально несет в себе  происхождение от глагола, а за счет приобретения признаков прилагательного способно им стать. Но как Часть Речи, можно сказать, оно остается именно причастием.

Comment: Кстати, в грамматике-80 другая теория. Есть отглагольные прилагательные со своими суффиксами, образованные от глаголов.  Смутная тема.  К примеру, способность совершать действие – это же не само действие. // Но мы  с вами по правилам работаем и отчитаться должны по правилам. Так что же делать? Я в двух давних темах всем рассказываю,что это прилагательное, слитное написание НЕ. Они мне не верят, но и доказать свою точку зрения тоже не могут. Так что делать?  Надо как-то закрыть тему.

Comment: Идти в своем направлении. Быть новатором. А в данном случае установщиком истины. Отглагольное прилагательное само по себе уже имеет глагольные функции (по происхождению). Становясь прилагательным, оно становится истинным причастием.

Comment: Ну кто нам поверит, нужна ссылка на правило. У меня есть версия, рассказать? Я не очень в ней уверена.

Comment: Рассказывайте. А правила давно пора переписать. Вот, например, кто-то первый написал сочетание ***декомпозиция насмотренности***, и без кавычек. Только недалёкий человек скажет "так нельзя, этого нет в словарях, сочетание слов непонятное, дайте ссылку". На то оно и развитие, чтобы обогащаться новым.

Comment: О,  так вы поменяли в своем комментарии на прилагательное? Сначала было причастие, и я обрадовался, что всем доказыватете это. Причастие всегда имеет олновременно обе свои стороны.

Comment: Смотрю в словарь: ПРОВЕТРИТЬ, -рю, -ришь; св. 1. что. Наполнить помещение свежим воздухом. П. спальню. П. зал. П. класс на перемене. Проветривать.  Смотрю в правило. Нужен производитель действия в Т.п. А кто здесь производитель действия? Комнату давно не проветривали. Неопр.-личное предложение. Неизвестный производитель, когда-то давно.  Откуда же мы возьмем Т.п.?  Хватит и наречия.  Как вам?

Comment: Неизвестный производитель, он же в любом случае есть. Т. п. вставляется легко. А про наречие не понял пока.

Comment: Нет, у Розенталя четкое правило для слов на МЫЙ.  Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется ТВОРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия: не любимый матерью ребёнок; движение, не тормозимое воздухом.
При наличии ДРУГИХ пояснительных слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на -мый (они теряют значения страдательности и приобретают качественное значение):

Comment: Забудьте о Розентале, вернее так, Розенталь это часть вашей насмотренности. В результате декомпозиции насмотренности мы ее выделили и никуда она от нас не денется. В общей насмотренности мы можем уже выделять другие виды и фокусироваться на них. // Прилагательное, образованное от глагола, становится причастием.

Comment: Не хочу, чтобы ушло в чат, предлагаю переместиться под вопрос.